# Import XML file into database but escape some of the XML tags

Tags: mysql, xml, mariadb

I'm able to successfully import XML files into a table in my database with the following query:

```
LOAD XML 
INFILE "myFileName.xml"
INTO TABLE t_orig2 
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<verse>';
```

That works when my XML is structured like this:

```
<verse id="40001001"><b>40</b><c>1</c><v>1</v><t>Text content here</verse>
```

The result is that the data nicely inserts into my table which has these columns:

```
id, b, c, v, t
```

The problem is that now I need to insert some actual XML tags into the "t" column in the database and there the import fails. My question is this: How can I indicate that some parts of my XML should not go into their own columns (but it should be interpreted as plain text instead)?

Here's an example of the problematic XML:

```
<verse id="40001001"><b>40</b><c>1</c><v>1</v><t>
<w pos="N-" morph="----NSF-" lemma="βίβλος" strongs="00976">Βίβλος</w> <w pos="N-" morph="----GSF-" lemma="γένεσις" strongs="01078">γενέσεως</w> <w pos="N-" morph="----GSM-" lemma="Ἰησοῦς" strongs="02424">Ἰησοῦ</w> <w pos="N-" morph="----GSM-" lemma="Χριστός" strongs="05547">χριστοῦ</w> <w pos="N-" morph="----GSM-" lemma="υἱός" strongs="05207">υἱοῦ</w> <w pos="N-" morph="----GSM-" lemma="Δαυίδ">Δαυὶδ</w> <w pos="N-" morph="----GSM-" lemma="υἱός" strongs="05207">υἱοῦ</w> <w pos="N-" morph="----GSM-" lemma="Ἀβραάμ" strongs="00011">Ἀβραάμ</w>.
</t></verse>
```

I'm after the end result where "id","b","c" and "v" go into their own columns in the database (which works nicely) but then everything that is inside the "t" tag should be put into the "t" column in the database as one long string.

How should I escape the XML inside the `<t></t>` tags so that the importer will insert it into the "t" column as one long string?

Comment: You need to replace the characters that have a special meaning in XML with their references by entity, like `<` with `&lt;` etc. or numeric. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)'s a list of predefined entities for XML.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks! I was kind of hoping there would be some way of not having to replace all those characters. I saw someone creating a "quote" from the XML in another answer using q[''] syntax but I was not able to adopt that successfully..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with loading XML directly, as XML instead of as text/blob, into a database.  However, converting those lines would not have to be so difficult.  Here is a Perl script that would change all of the `<t>` and `</t>` tags to `&lt;t>` and `&lt;/t>` respectively--and you could adjust the script to change other aspects as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#IF THESE NEXT TWO LINES RAISE ERRORS, YOU COULD TRY
#JUST COMMENTING THEM OUT (PUT A '#' IN FRONT OF THEM)
#THEY MAY NOT BE NEEDED, DEPENDING ON YOUR PERL SETUP
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use open ':encoding(utf8)'; # deal with all files in a UTF8 way

#https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my @data = ();
my $sourcefile = 'source_file.txt'; #FILE TO BE READ
my $targetfile = 'target_file.txt'; #IF EXISTS, THIS FILE WILL BE OVERWRITTEN!
my $longline = '';

#READ THE SOURCE FILE INTO MEMORY
    open SOURCE, "<$sourcefile" or die "Cannot open $sourcefile $!\n";
    @data = <SOURCE>;
    close SOURCE;

print "There are ".scalar @data." lines to process in the file.\n";

#PROCESS THE SOURCE FILE ONE LINE AT A TIME
    foreach my $line (@data) {
        $longline .= $line;
    }
    
#REPLACE CARRIAGE RETURNS WITH SPACES
    $longline =~ s/\n|\r/ /g;

$longline =~ s~
    <verse\sid="([^"]+)">
    <b>([^<]+)</b>
    <c>([^<]+)</c>
    <v>([^<]+)</v>
    <t>(.*?)</t>
    </verse>
    ~<verse id="$1"><b>$2</b><c>$3</c><v>$4</v>\&lt;t>$5\&lt;/t></verse>~xg;

#THE /x FLAG IS REQUIRED TO IGNORE MOST WHITESPACE,
#MAKING THE ABOVE MORE READABLE.  THE /g MAKES THE
#REPLACEMENT "GLOBAL", AND IF THE FILE IS ALL ON ONE
#LINE, IT MAY STILL DO ALL OF THE REQUIRED SUBSTITUTIONS.

    #ADD CARRIAGE RETURNS BACK IN FOLLOWING </verse> TAGS
    #IF ON WINDOWS, YOU MAY NEED \r\n INSTEAD OF \n.
    $longline =~ s~(</verse>)\s*~$1\n~g;

    
    open TARGET, ">$targetfile" or die "Cannot open $targetfile. $!\n";
    print TARGET $longline;
    close TARGET;

print "Script completed.\n";
print "You should now have one verse per line in $targetfile.\n\n";

exit;
```

To run the script on a computer with perl installed, just save it to a filename, e.g. "xml_fix_script.pl", and run it like this:

```
perl xml_fix_script.pl
```

Make sure your source file is in the same directory as the script--and it's always smart to keep a backup first, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use SmartXML. Check this example: https://redata.dev/smartxml/docs/type-conversion-in-xml-documents.html

1. You need to create structure of your table
2. Than generate parsing rule from UI
3. If you needed complex processing you could try use build-in grammar